# SharePoint 2013 with SQL 2012 License Query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server-2012, support, license

We have SharePoint 2013 with SQL 2012.

Microsoft support for SQL Server 2012 has ended.

Microsoft support for SP2013 is ending by 2023.

We cannot migrate SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016 as SP 2013 is not supported by SQL 2016.

Will Microsoft support SQL 2012 till SP2013 life cycle or how does this work?

Answer (score 2):

I guess not. You can use SQL Server 2014 but I guess it also will be out of support soon.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=SQL%20Server%202014

https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2016/11/04/sharepoint-2013-and-sql-server-2016/

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 with SP4 has extended end of life cycle which will end by 2022. [product lifecycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/?p1=16139)

You have to check with Microsoft account manager for clear dates. You dont need to upgrade to sql 2016 (as it is not supported), you can upgrade to Sql 2014 which is fully supported.